# Object references between two different object scopes are not allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, repository

I am trying to update User info but getting an error.

Controller code:

```
var User = (somr linq query).firstorDefault
```

Result from linq query comes in the form of my Viewmodel and my viewModel Class is like

```
public partial class UsersInformation
    {
        public TableUserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }
        public uint OwnerId { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }   
    }
```

And i am trying to Update data that comes in the form of ViewModel UsersInformation

```
User.LastLoginDT = DateTime.Now;
User.TermsnCondAcceptDtID = LatestTerms.Id;
User.TermsnCondAcceptDt = DateTime.Now;
UserAccountService.UpdateUserInfo(User); //Passing object to Service
```

The update code in the Service :

```
private static void updateInfo(tableUserAccount object)
{
    using (var con = new MyModelName())
    {
          con.Add(object);
          con.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The Error Message:

```
Object references between two different object scopes are not allowed.
The object 'Shared.Models.Tbluseraccount' is already managed by
'ObjectScopeImpl 0x1b' and was tried to be managed again by
'ObjectScopeImpl 0x1c OpenAccessRuntime.EnlistableObjectScope'.
```

Comment: I guess that your problem lay in UpdateUserInfo... show some code for that and the actual error message and you may get more replies.

Comment: See http://www.telerik.com/forums/object-scope-confliction

Comment: public static void UpdateUserInfo(TblUserAccount object)
        {
            using (var con = new HotelModel())
            {
                con.Add(object);
                con.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

Comment: Object references between two different object scopes are not allowed. The object 'Shared.Models.Tbluseraccount' is already managed by 'ObjectScopeImpl 0x1b' and was tried to be managed again by 'ObjectScopeImpl 0x1c OpenAccessRuntime.EnlistableObjectScope'.

Comment: If only as a test try putting your code inside the using statement, and fire the linq query using the context 'con'.

Comment: Your welcome. By the way you can always pass the 'con' context to methods as a parameter, so one using context method containing multiple methods that you pass the context to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was because you retrieved the entity using one context.

```
var User = (somr linq query).firstorDefault
```

Then you try to save the entity using a different context.

```
using (var con = new MyModelName())
{
      con.Add(object);
      con.SaveChanges();
}
```

Try the following:

```
using (var ctx = new MyModelName())
{
    var User = (some linq query using ctx).FirstOrDefault();

    object.LastLoginDT = DateTime.Now;
    object.TermsnCondAcceptDtID = 14;
    object.TermsnCondAcceptDt = DateTime.Now;

    updateInfo(object, ctx);
}

private static void updateInfo(tableUserAccount object, MyModelName ctx)
{
    ctx.Add(object);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```